# undefined method `payments' for #<Razorpay::Collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, payment, razorpay

If I try to fetch an order from Razorpray through this

```
order = Razorpay::Order.fetch(@razorpay_order_id)
payements = order.payments
```

I get error as undefined method `payments' for #<Razorpay::Collection: 0xabc4567890123>

Comment: This doesn't happens all the time but sometime this error occurs

Comment: check if the order was found, something like: 'payements = order.payments unless order.nil?'

Comment: did you tried handling razorpay exceptions? `Razorpay::BadRequestError` ?